# Why does SSIS think my non-unicode MySql data source is unicode?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, unicode, ssis

I'm currently attempting to clone a MySql database to a MSSQL db using SSIS. I already have done this via scheduled jobs in MSSQL Server Management Studio by using OPENQUERY, but I am trying to move over to SSIS for efficiency. 
The issue is that when connecting to MySql with either ado.net or ODBC, SSIS believes the datatypes to be unicode, which they are not.
Any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: This is default behavior and can be frustrating.  Options include OLEDB or setting up a field converter and converting from uni to non after the source in the dataflow.  Of course you could also use nvarchars in MSSQL....

Comment: Need more details on what you did or did not set in the way of character sets on both sides and in SSIS.  If possible, get the hex of any characters in any intermediate files.